# Trying to prove the Pythagorean theorem using Picks theorem.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

[Picks Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PicksTheorem.html) Let **A** be the area of a simply closed lattice square. Let **B** denote the number of lattice points on the square edges and **I** the number of points in the interior of the square. Then

$\large A=I + \frac{B}{2}-1$

Define three squares with areas

$\large A_{a} = I_{a} + \frac{B_{a}}{2}-1 = a^2$

$\large A_{b} = I_{b} + \frac{B_{b}}{2}-1 = b^2$

$\large A_{c} = I_{c} + \frac{B_{c}}{2}-1 = c^2$

[image: py_pi]

**Theorem**

For $B_{c}=4$, $A_{c} = A_{a} + A_{b}$.

**Proof**

Case $B_{c}=4$,

$\large A_{c} = I_{c} + \frac{4}{2}-1$

$\large A_{c} = I_{c} + 1$

Observe that

$\large I_{c} = A_{a} + A_{b} - 1$

Substituting $I_{c}$

$\large A_{c} = (A_{a} + A_{b} - 1) + 1$

$\large A_{c} = A_{a} + A_{b}$

$\therefore \large c^2 = a^2 + b^2 $

**Questions**

Is that a valid proof for specific case $B_{c}=4$?
For general cases, can Picks be applied to prove Pythagoras?

Thanks.

Comment: “Observe that”?

Comment: Yep, I observed that to be true. Although, I didn't prove it rigorously (beyond my ability).

Comment: There is no proof. You counted dots in this picture. Have you drawn other pictures of other triangles?

Comment: I tested this on many other pictures. My pattern intuition says it's true but would great if someone could justify it. (I have only a high school maths ability)

Comment: The only justification I see is the Pythagorean Theorem. Quite a circular argument.

Comment: The "base case"where $gcd(a,b)=1$ is all you need to prove, and if $gcd(a,b)=1$ then $B_c=4$ . But how do you prove that $B_c=4$ implies $I_c=A_a+A_b-1?$

Comment: I can't prove it. From earlier comments, proving that would amount to relying upon pythagoras which leads to circular reasoning. I only observed the relation between summed areas and the number of interior lattice points $I_{c}$.

Comment: I am not sure how easy it is to prove the Pythagorean relation - but may be this could be an way to calculate the numbers A and B of any square on the grid.

Comment: The way to prove is by calculating independently for a triangle located at the origin the three areas.

Comment: Are you still interested in a proof?

Comment: Sure. Open to any ideas you might have. Thanks!

Comment: Very innovative, well done pondering

Comment: @vengy Is the proof reasonable for you? Will you approve it?

Comment: Probably best to have someone more qualified in maths verify the solution.
I could start a bounty to attract more attention to your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it is **wrong** that Pythagoras' theorem can be proven using Picks' theorem. Picks' theorem only holds for polygons whose vertices have integer coordinates. Hence it **cannot** be used to prove the area-interpretation of Pythagoras' theorem for a triangle whose perpendicular sides have irrational ratio. If you use limit-based arguments to patch that, then it is far easier to use Jordan area as in [this post](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/11864/1550).

Comment: Did you understand my comment that the answer you accepted is wrong?? Just because it has upvotes does not imply anything about its correctness.

Comment: @moti would probably be the best person to discuss it. Thanks.

Comment: @vengy: As you can see, Moti is clearly not interested in responding. What I said is correct. Just ask any actual mathematician to confirm.

Comment: @user21820 - Moti did reply as a comment in his answer below: "@vengy it seems that you properly interpreted the image - assuming Picks leads to Bhaskara. What is nice/obvious that the same image may be used to directly prove either".

Comment: No, Moti failed to address [what I said two days ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8960943). If you're not interested in learning, this will be my last reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following describe a possible general proof. You just need to calculate the number of grid points in a triangle and the square as function of the sides of the right angle triangles.

[image]

Comment: The image looks a lot like Bhaskara Proof: http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~demo5337/Group3/Bhaskara.html
Could you explain your proof algebraically using Picks Theorem? Thanks.

Comment: You calculate the number of "points" - the equation that you have for picks theorem -  based on a and b for the triangles + the internal square. Than calculate the points based on c. The two values are equal - since the area of the large square equals the area of the 4 triangles + the small square.

Comment: Sorry ,I'm confused. Even if the two values are equal in "points", how does that prove $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$?

Comment: Because the "points" indicate area!!!

Comment: Thanks! Picks area is equal to Bhaskara area, and Bhaskara equals $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$, then Picks equals $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: @vengy it seems that you properly interpreted the image - assuming Picks leads to Bhaskara. What is nice/obvious that the same image may be used to directly prove either.